# Getting a consistent full background in the entire html doc's body

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm trying to give my page a full background in its body but nothing is working and the output I'm getting is rubbish.

I've tried everything I could think of, but nothing is doing right. Can you please tell me where my mistake is? (the .jpg is in the correct place)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                height: 100px;
                width: 100px;
                background-image:url(background.jpg) repeat fixed 100% 100%;
            }

            #container {
                width: 979px;
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0 auto;
                background-color: blue;
            }

        </style>
        <title> Baisbook </title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <p> Just saying Hi! </p>
        </div>
        <p>This is a Test</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think yhe image not exist or the image path is not correct.

or try this

```
            background-image:url('background.jpg');
```

This statement is enough

Answer (score 0):

Is your image able to show up but not filling all the wanted area? If it is then try this sample codes in your body area to see if it works.

```
body { 
  background: url(background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In background-image remove the image put just background and background position is center top....

```
 body {
       height: 100px;
       width: 100px;
       background:url(background.jpg) no-repeat fixed center top;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

use below code

```
 body {
background:url(your image path) repeat fixed 100% 100%;
background-attachment:fixed;
background-size:100%;
background:url(your image path) repeat fixed center center  \9;
/*IE 9*/
background:url(your image path) repeat fixed top 100% /IE9;
background-attachment:fixed /IE9;
background-size:100% /IE9;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

if Ok with you to used basic `css code` to apply `background-image`

Instead of these

```
body {
       height: 100px;
       width: 100px;
       background-image:url(background.jpg) no-repeat fixed 100% 100%;
    }
```

try this

```
body {
           height: 100px;
           width: 100px;
           background-image:url(background.jpg);
           background-repeat:no-repeat;
           background-position:fixed;
           background-size:100%;

        }
```

Working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/QsDwS/)